# Best practice for listing all files in a document library?

Tags: 2010, development

The [Microsoft Best Practices for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949%28v=office.12%29.aspx) guide recommends not enumerating entire SPList.Items collections or SPFolder.Files collections.

I have the need to generate a list of all files in the farm, but I'd like to do it in a way that's considered good practice. How should I approach this?

Comment: why don't you just drop a List View Web Part ?

Comment: does it matter in what way you do it? like in a webpart, application or through powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SPQuery - you can limit ammount of retrieved items per request and add custom filters

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Your List Title"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";
// OPTIONAL // query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>[Your Content Type ID]</Value></Eq></Where>";
query.RowLimit = 1000;
do
{
    SPListItemCollection itemColl = list.GetItems(query);
    foreach (SPListItem item in itemColl)
    {
        // DO YOUR STUFF
    }
    query.ListItemCollectionPosition = itemColl.ListItemCollectionPosition;
} while (query.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
```